# BaseX XQUERY selecting nodes with the value of a specific attribute

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

XML sample:

```
    <mondial>
        <continent id="f0_119" name="Europe"/>
        <continent id="f0_123" name="Asia"/>
        <continent id="f0_126" name="America"/>
        <continent id="f0_129" name="Australia/Oceania"/>
        <continent id="f0_132" name="Africa"/>
        <country id="f0_136" name="Albania" capital="f0_1461" population="3249136"
                 datacode="AL" total_area="28750" population_growth="1.34"
                 infant_mortality="49.2" gdp_agri="55" gdp_total="4100"
                 inflation="16" indep_date="28 11 1912"
                 government="emerging democracy" car_code="AL">
            <name>Albania</name>
            <city id="f0_1461" country="f0_136" longitude="10.7" latitude="46.2">
                <name>Tirane</name>
                <population year="87">192000</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_36498" country="f0_136" longitude="19.2" latitude="42.2">
                <name>Shkoder</name>
                <population year="87">62000</population>
                <located_at type="lake" water="f0_39058"/>
            </city>
        </country>
    </mondial>
```

```
for $x in //mondial/country/population
where $x/@year=87
return $x/name
```

I'm basically trying to return `<name>` from the node `<population>` that has the attribute of `year=87`. I know it sounds confusing as heck, I can't even find documentation for this I've tried googling how to select using the attribute but I can't seem to return anything.

Comment: I properly formatted your XML , so you can easily see its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XQuery.

**XQuery**

```
for $x in //mondial/country/city
where $x/population/@year=87
return $x/name
```

Comment: it does return the value of `<population>` but I need the `<name>` is that possible?

Comment: @OscarCubz, I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the `population` elements in your XML document are children of the `city` elements. Next, you tried to loop over the `population` elements, and it’s better to move this path step into the `where` clause. One solution for returning the city names is as follows:

```
for $city in /mondial/country/city
where $city/population/@year = 87
return $city/name
```

Comment: You where a bit late but you and @Yitzhak Khabinsky's answer was right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the required information with a single XPath

```
//city[population/@year=87]/name
```

[Live Demo (xqueryfiddle)](https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPsa)